# SharePoint 2019 shows blank pages after the KB5001945 Security Update

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, administration, 2019, patching

After installing the SharePoint 2019 KB5001945 Security Update, today all document libraries and lists show nothing but a blank page. This occurs even on the Central Admin site. Does anyone know the best way to fix it? Should we roll-back the CU? Anyone is facing the same issue?

[Similar issue is reported here yesterday](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/481157/sharepoint-2019-not-working-after-lates-update.html?childToView=483586#answer-483586).

Comment: Did you also install KB5001944?

Comment: No, it wasn't installed. It looks like a language pack was installed without any other updates. It wasn't me, but I am trying to help someone with this issue.

Comment: You _must_ install both updates from each month, even if you are only using the en-us version of SharePoint Server. If a locale-specific update isn't available for that particular month, you must have the _most recent_ loacale-specific update installed. Install that KB and re-run the Config WIzard.

Comment: Thank you Trevor. We'll try doing it.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this article](https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2021/07/13/july-2021-cu-for-sharepoint-server-2019-is-available-for-download/),

> It is required to install both fixes (language dependent and
> independent) to fully patch a SharePoint server.

Have you installed both two fixes? Please install both fixes.

Answer (score 0):

It is always recommended install both Language dependent and independent update ad then run psconfig wizard. Not sure if you can roll back SharePoint update unless you have taken Image level backup of SharePoint Servers and SQL servers